# Is it better to have multiple groupby for different functionalities or implement functionalities within a single group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I want to add 3 columns (A,B,C) to an existing dataframe. Each column requires some processing on the existing dataframe. Also the processing has to be done on a group of rows defined by a column 'code'.

So my question is which is faster

```
df.groupby('code').apply(generate_A)
df.groupby('code').apply(generate_B)
df.groupby('code').apply(generate_C)
```

or

```
df.groupby('code').apply(generate_A_B_C)
```

where generate_A_B_C is a function which calls generate_A, generate_B, generate_C on the group defined by 'code'.

```
df['rsi_1_increases_above_lower_threshold_Close'] = df.groupby('SecuritiesCode').apply(detect_if_RSI_crosses_above_lower_threshold,
                                                                                                          rsi_lower_threshold = rsi_lower_threshold,
                                                                                                          rsi_column='rsi_1_Close')

df['rsi_1_decreases_below_upper_threshold_Close'] = df.groupby('SecuritiesCode').apply(detect_if_RSI_crosses_below_upper_threshold,
                                                                                                          rsi_upper_threshold = rsi_upper_threshold,
                                                                                                          rsi_column='rsi_1_Close')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I guess second one, but depends of functions.

Comment: A,B and C contains the moving averages of 3 different columns a,b,c

Comment: Can you add code to question?

Comment: Added the original code.

Comment: I experimented just now with both possibilities and both take approximately the same time (72 seconds). Weird. It may mean that there may be some bottleneck some where in my code which is dominating execution time.

Comment: I ee your code, it is call for multiple columns? Your code is 2 times same, it is fine?

Comment: The column names are different

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the operation you're trying to benchmark (function + input data). We can't give you a clear answer because we don't know the details of what you're trying to measure.